# Modeling nose pads on glasses design

Tags: modeling

I'm a beginner with Blender, and I'm designing sunglasses. Everything went pretty good so far, but I'm currently struggling with the nose pads part.

I started with an extrusion, but I cant find any way to transform it into the thin and smooth nose pads.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you !
[image]
[image]

EDIT : I manage to get to this point but it's not perfect.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried subdivision surface?

Comment: Hello :). Please add an image of what exactly you're going for.

Comment: @JachymMichal Done :) Sorry about the quality, I didnt find a clean one...

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 I tried to subdivisioned the edges to create verticies in order to create a middle edge but I dont know how to proceed after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following........

1: Extrude out a couple of the faces.
[image]

2: Add a Subdivision modifier.
[image]

3: Select the upper edge loop and slide it up towards the next edge loop.
( <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>G</kbd> to edge slide ). See screenshot below. Then    repeat for the other edge loop.
[image]

4: Select the middle 2 vertices and drag them out a little to form the  curve.
[image]

5: After setting all the faces to **Smooth Shading**, (select all, **Face** menu > **Shade Smooth**) enable the **Auto Smooth** option from the **Object Data Properties** tab.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm new as well but I would add a subsurface modifier and use proportional editing (shortcut: O) to bring out that bump.